# SparkR window function

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, sparkr

I found from [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10043) that 1.6 release of `SparkR` has implemented window functions including `lag` and `rank`, but `over` function is not implemented yet. How can I use window function like `lag` function without `over` in `SparkR`(not the `SparkSQL` way)? Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Spark 2.0.0+**

SparkR provides DSL wrappers with `over`, `window.partitionBy` / `partitionBy`, `window.orderBy` / `orderBy` and `rowsBetween` / `rangeBeteen` functions.

**Spark <= 1.6**

Unfortunately it is not possible in 1.6.0. While some window functions, including `lag`, have been implemented SparkR doesn't support window definitions yet which renders these completely useless.

As long as [SPARK-11395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11395) is not resolved the only option is to use raw SQL:

```
set.seed(1)

hc <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
sdf <- createDataFrame(hc, data.frame(x=1:12, y=1:3, z=rnorm(12)))
registerTempTable(sdf, "sdf")

sql(hc, "SELECT x, y, z, LAG(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY x) FROM sdf") %>% 
  head()

##    x y          z        _c3
## 1  1 1 -0.6264538         NA
## 2  4 1  1.5952808 -0.6264538
## 3  7 1  0.4874291  1.5952808
## 4 10 1 -0.3053884  0.4874291
## 5  2 2  0.1836433         NA
## 6  5 2  0.3295078  0.1836433
```

Assuming that the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10094) will be merged without significant changes window definition and example query should look as follows:

```
w <- Window.partitionBy("y") %>% orderBy("x")
select(sdf, over(lag(sdf$z), w))
```