# SparkR window function : Error "Task not serializable"

Tags: r, hive, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I try to test `Window function` thanks to Spark SQL module from SparkR.
I use Spark 1.6 and I try to replicate the example provided by [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885981/sparkr-window-function) in two different deploy modes (`local` and `yarn-client`).

```
set.seed(1)

hc <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
sdf <- createDataFrame(hc, data.frame(x=1:12, y=1:3, z=rnorm(12)))
registerTempTable(sdf, "sdf")

query <- sql(hc, "SELECT x, y, z, LAG(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY x) FROM sdf") 
head(query)

##    x y          z        _c3
## 1  1 1 -0.6264538         NA
## 2  4 1  1.5952808 -0.6264538
## 3  7 1  0.4874291  1.5952808
## 4 10 1 -0.3053884  0.4874291
## 5  2 2  0.1836433         NA
## 6  5 2  0.3295078  0.1836433
```

But for the two deployment modes, I get the same error when i execute the Spark Action `head(query)` :

```
16/01/21 18:03:17 ERROR r.RBackendHandler: dfToCols on     org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:707)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Window.doExecute(Window.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.
```

I tried this HQL query directly into HIVE and working properly. Also "normal" queries like `classical_query <- sql(hc, "SELECT * FROM sdf") 
head(classical_query)`
 works fine.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
It was just a Spark configuration problem.

I just removed the `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-exec.jar` JAR from the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` variable in the `spark-defaults.conf`configuration file.