# Spark DataFrame - group rows based on difference of timestamp using R

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a spark DataFrame like this:

```
timestamp            userId
2016-07-26 12:05:00   a
2016-07-26 12:05:01   b
2016-07-26 12:05:02   c
2016-07-26 12:05:03   d
2016-07-26 12:05:04   e
2016-07-26 12:05:05   f
```

I want to group the rows that are within 5 sec difference in one group, like:

```
timestamp            userId   group
2016-07-26 12:05:00   a        1  
2016-07-26 12:05:01   b        1
2016-07-26 12:05:02   c        1
2016-07-26 12:05:03   d        1
2016-07-26 12:05:04   e        1
2016-07-26 12:05:05   f        2
```

Is there a way to do this without converting the spark DataFrame into R dataframe?

Comment: Since you want to process it in R, you will need to use a suitable data structure in R, isn't that so?

Comment: Are you using `sparkR`? Which version?

Comment: @Sotos it's 1.6.2

Comment: You will need to use Window functions, but these have only been implemented with Spark 2.0 for SparkR.

Comment: @mtoto You [can use window functions in 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34885981/1560062) just fine. But you cannot easily apply these to these problem to get exact solution and decent performance.

Answer (score 0):

This particular functionality is commonly known as Sessionization and frequently used by web analysts to identify sessions for a particular user.
There are built in UDFs in hive which can be used with sparksqlcontext.
For example,
https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/udfs