# SparkR DataFrame partitioning issue

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In my R script, I have a `SparkDataFrame` of two columns (time, value) containing data for four different months. Because of the fact that I need to apply my function to an each month separately, I figured I would `repartition` it into four partitions where each of them would hold data for a separate month.

I created an additional column called partition, having an integer value 0 - 3 and after that called the `repartition` method by this specific column.

Sadly as it's being described in this topic:
[Spark SQL - Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby), with the `repartition` method we are only sure that all the data with the same key will end up in the same partition, however data with a different key can also end up in the same partition.

In my case, executing code visible below results in creating 4 partitions but populating only 2 of them with data.

I guess I should be using the `partitionBy` method, however in case of SparkR I have no idea how to do that. 
The official documentation states that this method is applied to something called `WindowSpec` and not a `DataFrame`.

I would really appreciate some help with this matter as I have no idea how to incorporate this method into my code.

```
sparkR.session(
   master="local[*]",  sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.shuffle.partitions="4"))
df <- as.DataFrame(inputDat) # this is a dataframe with added partition column
repartitionedDf <- repartition(df, col = df$partition)

schema <- structType(
  structField("time", "timestamp"), 
  structField("value", "double"), 
  structField("partition", "string"))

processedDf <- dapply(repartitionedDf, 
  function(x) { data.frame(produceHourlyResults(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) },
  schema)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong method. If you

> need to apply my function to an each month separately

you should use [`gapply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/gapply.html) that

> Groups the SparkDataFrame using the specified columns and applies the R function to each group.

```
df %>% group_by("month") %>% gapply(fun, schema)
```

or

```
df %>% gapply("month", fun, schema)
```

---

> In my case, executing code visible below results in creating 4 partitions but populating only 2 of them with data.

This suggests hash collisions. Increasing number of partitions reasonably above the number of unique keys should resolve the problem:

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 17
```

---

> I guess i should be using the partitionBy method, however

No. `partitionBy` is used with [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) ([SparkR window function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34885981/8371915)).

---

To address [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464684/sparkr-dataframe-partitioning-issue#comment83923267_48464860):

> i decided to use dapply with separate partitions in order to be able to easily save each month into separate CSV file

Hash partitioner doesn't work like that [How does HashPartitioner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/8371915)

You can try with `partitionBy` in the writer, but I am not sure if it directly supported in SparkR. It is supported in structured streaming, for batch you may have to call Java methods or use tables with metastore:

```
createDataFrame(iris) %>% createOrReplaceTempView("iris_view")
sql(
    "CREATE TABLE iris 
    USING csv PARTITIONED BY(species)
    LOCATION '/tmp/iris' AS SELECT * FROM iris_view"
)
```

Comment: I do have it enabled. Now i actually noticed, that when i issued the CREATE command without LOCATION clause it saved the dataframe to the default location\spark-warehouse folder.
This default location can be changed by setting the: `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to desired value.

Comment: And what version of Spark do you use? I see it doesn't work before 2.2.

Comment: Yea then that is the case, i have 2.1.1. Ill try to update it to the newer version.