# Ungroup SparkR data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a spark data frame:

```
library(SparkR); library(magrittr)

as.DataFrame(mtcars) %>%
   groupBy("am")
```

How can I ungroup this data frame? There doesn't seems to be any ungroup function in the SparkR library!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There doesn't seems to be any ungroup function in the SparkR library

That's because `groupBy` doesn't have the same meaning as `group_by` in `dplyr`.

`SparkR::group_by` / `SparkR::groupBy` returns not a `SparkDataFrame` but a `GroupData` object which corresponds to `GROUP BY` clause in SQL. To convert it back to a `SparkDataFrame` you should call `SparkR::agg` (or if you prefer `dplyr` nomenclature `SparkR::summarize`) which corresponds to `SELECT` component of the `SQL` query.

Once you aggregate you get back `SparkDataFrame` and grouping is no longer present.

Additionally `SparkR::groupBy` doesn't have dplyr `group_by(...) %>% mutate(...)` equivalent. Instead we use [window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34885981/10465355) with frame definition.

So the take away message is - if you don't plan to aggregate don't use `groupBy`.